# Add text to metabox input text field from Thickbox

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery, metabox, thickbox

I have a custom post type with a metabox text input area that I want to have a shortcode inserted into from a thickbox when a link is clicked on from the modal window. Using the code below right now it just closes the modal window when the insert button is clicked. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

I have the thick box opening fine.

The page that is rendered has the link as this:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" style="display:block" class="button insertdownload" id="download-'.$d->id.'">Insert</a></td>';
```

I have the jQuery call as:

```
jQuery('.insertdownload').click(function(){

var did = jQuery(this).attr('id');

did=did.replace('download-', '');

if (jQuery('#format').val()>0) {

jQuery('#my_new_field').val('[download id="' + did + '" format="' + 

jQuery('#format').val() + '"]');

} else {

jQuery('#my_new_field').val('[download id="' + did + '"]');

}

window.parent.tb_remove();
});
```

I also have my metabox text field as:

```
<input type="text" size="25" name="myplugin_new_field" id="my_new_field">
```

This was the original code but I didn't want it to go to the editor window, I want it to go to my input field.

```
jQuery('.insertdownload').click(function(){
var win = window.dialogArguments || opener || parent || top;
var did = jQuery(this).attr('id');
did=did.replace('download-', '');
if (jQuery('#format').val()>0) win.send_to_editor('[download id="' + did + '" format="' + jQuery('#format').val() + '"]');
else win.send_to_editor('[download id="' + did + '"]');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, since it was an iframe I guess I was needing to target the parent window.

```
    jQuery('.insertdownload').click(function(){
    var did = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    did=did.replace('download-', '');
    if (jQuery('#format').val()>0) {
    parent.jQuery('#my_new_field').val('[download id="' + did + '" format="' + jQuery('#format').val() + '"]');
    } else {
    parent.jQuery('#my_new_field').val('[download id="' + did + '"]');
    }
    window.parent.tb_remove(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code in;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

// your code here...

});
```

...and in fact your code should look like this;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.insertdownload').click(function(){

    var did = 'this is only a test';

    did=did.replace('download-', '');

    if ($('#format').val('1')) {

    $('#my_new_field').val('[download id="' + did + '" format="' + 

    $('#format').val() + '"]');

    } else {

    $('#my_new_field').val('[download id="' + did + '"]');

    }

    window.parent.tb_remove(); 

    });

});
​
```

Check out the Fiddle here... [LINKAGE](http://jsfiddle.net/fQGsg/)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me. I tried your code and now the window no longer closes and the value is not inserted. I also needed the check for the #format value to see if it is larger than zero (that is a select dropdown that I want to do the first part of the if/else statement if the value is larger than 0.